# copy to multiple lines with increasing number

Tags: vim

Is there a way in vim to copy below line to multiple lines with number increasing after @

i.e. 
`XMMN26@1   MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac`

becomes

```
XMMN26@1   MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac 

XMMN26@2   MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac 

XMMN26@3   MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac 

XMMN26@4   MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac
```

is there a way to do that?

thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the lines for as many times you want using

```
Y5p   -- Yanks current line and copies it 5 times
```

and use a find/replace to have an incremental number

```
%s/1 /\=line('.').' '
```

Note that the `\=line('.')` uses the current linenumber. Depending on your requirements, you might want to add like this `%s/1 /\=line('.')+5.' '`

**Edit**

Some alternatives. In the end, it all depends on making sure that the search command finds the correct location to replace

```
%s/1/\=line('.')     -- this will fail if there's a 1 before the actual @1

%s/@1/\='@'.line('.')

%s/@\zs1/\=line('.')

%s/1\ze /\=line('.')
```

Comment: Thanks Lieven,   %s/1 /\=line('.') seems also work, then what is the effect of   . '  ' after line('.') ?

Comment: @user11853665 - I search for a `1` followed by a `space`. The `.' '` is to add the space again to the replaced text.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way to do that?

Yes, you need `:h v_g_ctrl-a`. That is:

1) make copies of the source line;

2) Use visual block mode to select those "numbers" (except the first one);

3) Do `g^A`. Voila.

So, the full sequence is `yy3pE^V2jg^A`

Comment: Thanks Matt. In my usage case, I actually need to copy to a large number of lines with increasing number, in which case I cannot manually select those numbers..

Comment: @user11853665 Then, please, revise your question. Perhaps, `%s` and `\=`, as @LievenKeersmaekers suggests, will be more useful then. However, there could be no complete answer until you set your starting conditions.

Comment: @user11853665 You may also want to read [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/688/how-to-add-permanent-line-numbers-to-a-file).

Comment: Thanks Matt!  sorry I wasn't clear in original question

Comment: `g^A` is definitely worth remembering, tx. If you replace the `26` in `XMMN26` with whatever that's not a number, you can select all en just use `g^A`.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Yes, `g^A` skips everything which does not look like a number, the same way, say, `^A` does in normal mode. However, it has no parameter to skip the numbers themselves, so here a cursor/selection movement was needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using macros

```
:let @a=""
:let @a="yypf@\<c-a>"
10@a
```

On the first line we clean the macro 'a'

On the second line we define macro 'a'

```
 yy ..................... copy the first line
 p ...................... paste the copied line
 f@ ..................... jumps to @
 \<c-a> ................. as if you typed Ctrl-a (increase number)
```

OBS: In order to use keystrokes like control or shift your macro needs to be between double quotes instead of single quotes.

On the third line we call macro 'a' 10 times

Comment: Good short macro, but the underlying commands could probably use some explanation for the OP

Comment: Thanks Sergio for the reply. the 2nd line, yyf@\<c-a> part,  for my particular case, what should I replace it with?  I actually tried :let @a="yyf@\<c-a>" (as is),   :let @a="XMMN26@\<c-a>" , also :let @a="XMMN26@1", they all returned "Invalid range". sorry I'm rather new so may miss something obvious.

Comment: I hope the notes a wrote can help you better now @user11853665

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, so I check again, and found that everytime after I hit "10@a", instead of generating 10 new lines with incremental number, it instead increment the number after @ in the same line;     I also noticed that for 10@a to take effect, the cursor has to be before the number.  So looks like I'm still missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I had forget the `p` in the macro. I hope this new version will work. If you look at the macro, now, it has the p command

Answer (score 0):

My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) has (among many others) a `gpp` mapping that pastes with the first decimal number found on or after the current cursor column.

So in your example it would be `^eyy3gpp` (*go to end of first column, yank line, special-paste with increment 3 times*).

Answer (score 0):

You may use `for` loop and `put`:

```
:for i in range(1,10) | put ='XMMN26@'.i.'  MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac'  | endfor
```

Result:

```
XMMN26@1  MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac
XMMN26@2  MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac
XMMN26@3  MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac
XMMN26@4  MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac
XMMN26@5  MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac
XMMN26@6  MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac
XMMN26@7  MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac
XMMN26@8  MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac
XMMN26@9  MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac
XMMN26@10  MMN26:D MMN26:G MMN26:S VSS nch_12od15_mac
```

Modified the example from:
https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Making_a_list_of_numbers